# How to POST to GenericAPIView from a TemplateView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have an API endpoint which activates a user's account. It expects `uid` and `token` in form data.

Certainly, it is a UX flaw to expect the user to POST to my endpoint

So they get an email with a link (containing a `uid` and `token`) for activating their account

like: `http://example.com/api/auth/account/activate/{uid}/{token}`

e.g. `https://example.com/api/auth/account/activate/MzA/562-5bb096a051c6210994fd`

So when clicked, the view for that link POSTs their data to the API endpoint and returns a templated page. My working implementation:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('activate/<str:uid>/<str:token>',  views.ActivationView.as_view(), name='activate')
]
```

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from djoser.views import ActivationView as DjoserActivationView
from django.test.client import RequestFactory


class ActivationView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "users/activation.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_data = {
            'uid': kwargs['uid'],
            'token': kwargs['token']
        }

        alt_request = RequestFactory().post('/api/auth/users/confirm/', form_data)
        activate_view_response = DjoserActivationView.as_view()(alt_request)

        kwargs['activation_status_code'] = activate_view_response.status_code

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, I do not think it is okay for me to be using `RequestFactory` the way I did here. I don't know any other way I could achieve this. What options are available with Django?

Comment: Well, I deleted my answer, because it might be bit misguiding. So, I think its best to create some sort of service functions which can be used in both `/api/auth/users/confirm/` view and `ActivationView` view. Anyway, regarding DjoserActivation view, you need to call it via url regardless

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the logic in [ActivationView](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/views.py#L246) is implemented as a single method, `_action`. So you could make your own view a subclass of that view and call the method in `get`.

```
class ActivationView(DjoserActivationView):

    template_name = "users/activation.html"

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=kwargs)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            response = self._action(serializer)
            kwargs['activation_status_code'] = activate_view_response.status_code

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note, I'm not familiar with Djoser and I don't really understand why they want you to implement it as a POST in the first place; they presumably have a good reason for doing so, so you should think carefully about whether you really want to do this.